# URLSession produces '()', not the expected contextual result type

Tags: ios, swift3

Any clue why am I getting error "'URLSession' produces '()', not the expected contextual result type 'URLSession'" for the below line -

```
internalSession = URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default)
```

[image]

I'm using latest Xcode and swift 3. I have found similar questions & answers on stackoverflow and tried them but they didn't have working/accepted answers.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Please check your Delegate methods for URLSessionTaskDelegate or URLSessionDelegate and try to match as per swift 3. This worked for me.